# Estimating a contour integral which includes the riemann zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I would like to understand the following paper, it is about the Erdös-Kac theorem http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa4/aa417.pdf (Site 75). My problem is to estimate $$I_2 := \dfrac{1}{2 \pi i } \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} \dfrac{n^s \mu(s,u)}{s^2} \left( \zeta(s)^{e^{iu}}-\dfrac{1}{(s-1)^{e^{iu}}} \right) ds$$
where $|\mu(s,u)| \leq Ce^{|u|}$ for $Re(s) \geq 1$.
I would like to show $$I_2 =O(n/log(n))$$
where $\zeta$ is as usual the riemann zeta function. Basically I would like to transform the integral to line $1$ but I don't how to handle the singularity at $s=1$. 
The idea of the paper is that
$ \dfrac{(\zeta(s)(s-1))^{e^{iu}}-1}{(s-1)^{e^{iu}}}  $
is continous at $s=1$ but why we have  $(\zeta(s)(s-1))^{e^{iu}}=(\zeta(s)))^{e^{iu}}(s-1))^{e^{iu}}$? Some ideas? It is possible if there is only a removable singularity to handle the transformation to line 1?

Comment: My guess - and I stress, this is a guess, so please take this with many grains of salt - is that there is a branch point singularity at $s=1$.  Thus, what you might want to do is introduce a Bromwich contour that respects a branch cut along the part of the real axis where $\operatorname{Re}{z} \lt 1$.

Comment: @RonGordon : yes. if $a$ is not an integer and $h(s)$ is holomorphic,  $h(s)^a$ has branch points where $h(s)  = 0$. since $h(s) = (s-1) \zeta(s)$ is holomorphic and $h(1)=1$ :  $g(s) = h(s)^a$ has branch points only at the zeros of $\zeta(s)$ but is holomorphic at $s=1$, with $g(1) = 1$. hence $g(s)-1$ is holomorphic at $s=1$ with a zero of order $1$ there (with $g'(1) = \gamma$),  and $\frac{g(s)-1}{(s-1)^a} = \zeta(s)^a - \frac{1}{(s-1)^a}$ is $\sim \gamma (s-1)^{1-a}$ at $s=1$, and hence has a branch point there.

Comment: @ niemannski : everything is written in your link, you didn't read it !

Comment: @ user1952009 sorry if it seems so I didn't read it,  but I dont't understand why this implies we can  transform it to line 1.